# Recommended TargetFrameworks for NuGet packages

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I am about to create some Nuget packages and I am trying to find any recommendations for setting target frameworks for NuGet packages. Unfortunately I haven't found any good references for this (except the [Cross-Platform targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting) documentation which states that all libraries should reference netstandard2.0).

If I look at Microsofts NuGet packages they are doing it quite differently here are some examples from the extensions related packages:

- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions only refers to netstandard2.0
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging refers to netcoreapp3.1 and netstandard2.0
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection refers to netcoreapp3.1, netstandard2.1 and netstandard2.0.

  - The netstandard2.0 uses the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces so this is a difference between that target and the others.
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions refers to netcoreapp3.1 and netstandard2.0

  - Also here the netstandard2.0 uses the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, but the difference is that in this package there is no netstandard2.1 reference which causes a library that references netstandard2.1 (that has support for async interfaces) to have a reference to this non-netstandard2.1 library?

So, why does all almost all new NuGet packages include the netcoreapp3.x target framework but don't include netstandard 2.1? I can see the reason of netstandard2.0, but not the reason for including netcoreapp3.x without or instead of netstandard2.1.

(The reason I write netcoreapp3.x instead of netcoreapp3.0 and/or netcoreapp3.1 is because this is done in both netcoreapp3.0 and netcoreapp3.1 versions of the NuGet packages).

Comment: Who's your audience? Do you reference other NuGet packages?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are referring to with audience here, but my package is intended to be used for all frameworks that at least supports .NET Standard 2.0 (Currently I don't plan to use any 2.1 features) and ultimately be available on NuGet.org.

Answer (score 0):

The nuget package target that you chose should be compatible with the target framework of your project.

An useful article that helps understand the difference between .NET Core and .NET Standard: [Demystifying .NET Core and .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/net-standard-demystifying-net-core-and-net-standard)

Here is a table that shows what what .NET Core target supports what .NET Standard

[image]

[Image reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support)

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-1/) you can find more specific information about the changes that that .NET Core 3.1 has.

Keep in mind that you can also add several framework targets to your nuget package.

Comment: Yes, I know all about this, however the real question why target framework in some packages netcoreapp3.0 and not netstandard2.1? Why's that? There is no clear documentation or recommendation on this in any of your references here.

Comment: I hope the following article will help answer your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/net-standard-demystifying-net-core-and-net-standard

Comment: So if you target .NET Standard 2.0 you can consume the package on applications that targets: .NET Core 2.0, .NET Framework 4.6.1, Mono 5.4, etc ( as showed on the table above ). So I recommend targeting .NET Standard 2.0+ because your nuget package will be able to be used by the corresponding version of the other frameworks.

Comment: @AnnaMaule, if you look at e.g. the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package, it refers to both netstandard2.0 _and_ netcoreapp3.1 (but not netstandard2.1!). The question is: Why do it this way? Is this an example third-party package authors should follow?  My colleague believes he read something somewhere about this, but do not recall the details.

Comment: Because if they targeted netstandard2.1 they would force people to have their solution targeted to netstandar2.1 and only .NET Core 3.1 and everyone in that columns would be able to use that nuget package. By duo targeting .net standard 2.0 and netcoreapp3.1 they allow the frameworks under .NET Standard 2.0 plus the  .NET Core 3.1 to consume the package

Comment: @AnnaMaule Yes, but that's for netstandard2.0. Thats clear why it is, to target a broader audience (that is stated quite clear in the initial link I referred). 

But that's not what I was wondering about. It is why it has target framework netcoreapp3.1 and not netstandard2.1 (that is in more clear word. Why does many libraries refers netstandard2.0 and netcoreapp3.1 and not netstandard2.0, netstandard2.1 and netcoreapp3.1 (that is including netstandard2.1 as a part of the target frameworks))?

Comment: Added a comment to https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/8407 document issue around the same issue which has been open for over a year...